# How to load different Pie charts for different values in UITableview using Core Plot

Tags: core-plot

I loaded pie charts in tableview in each row, but all the pie chart loaded with first pie chart values. Each row pie chart should load with different values.How to set that.Sample code is appreciated.Thx guys.

Answer (score 0):

Give each pie chart a unique `identifier`. Check this property in the datasource to identify the plot requesting data and return the correct values. The *Plot Gallery* example app includes several pie chart demos.